# Why is rendering image placeholders entirely on the client side desirable?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, placeholder

I couldn't help but notice a lot of traction around the [Holder.js Github repo](https://github.com/imsky/holder) recently.

I'm a novice, so bear with me, but I can't fathom why rendering image placeholders entirely on the client side is such a big win. Does this reduce development complexity somehow? Are there performance gains?

Just trying to better understand how this fits into the grand scheme of things.

Comment: It helps to remove outside factors from wire-framing and general testing.

Comment: Also, it allows for offline development.

Comment: Imagine, for example, that you're using `http://placehold.it` to serve up images for you. If your internet connection or their servers go down, you're stuck with broken links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this reduce development complexity somehow?

Yes, because you don’t need any backend or third-party services to serve decent placeholders while prototyping layouts.

> Are there performance gains?

Compared to using a third party service that serves kittens or whatever, then yes it will be faster. It will also be faster than serving images from the backend.

However, I personally prefer using plain CSS for placeholders instead.

Comment: Plain CSS won't work to test image scaling behavior on the `img` tag.

Comment: Dude, I totally want a third party service that serves kittens.

Comment: @Shmiddty how is that? Just add a background color to the `IMG` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/ZhngW/

Comment: @David Solid colors can't indicate aspect ratios...

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo http://placekitten.com

Comment: @Shmiddty good point, I never found myself in such need though. Naturally there are some benefits using a canvas as a placeholder over CSS, hence the project, but it’s not in my toolbox.

Comment: @David From the looks of it, it doesn't actually use a canvas as the placeholder. It uses the canvas to generate a base64 string representing the image, then sets the image's src to that value. It's pretty interesting, I never knew something like that was possible.